# Django MySql, how to get timestamp functionality

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, timestamp

Before introducing Django I had a table for time series data that used the MySQL type "timestamp" for the `timestamp` field.  I could easily insert my time series data into the table, with timestamps as strings such as `"2014-08-23 20:31:50.133709 -0700"`

After introducing Django and creating a model to represent the table, I had to use the datatype `models.DateTimeField().`  This generates the SQL type `"datetime".`  With that type, I am now getting the

```
error:
"Warning: Out of range value for column 'timestamp' at row 1".
```

*How do I either make my string `timestamp` values work with `datetime`, or get Django to generate a `MySQL timestamp` type?*

Comment: check this code: https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/db/models.py